# Unable to display new lines for array data in UILabel

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uilabel, multiline

I have an array. In that I have data like

```
"multi": ["New York","Los Angeles", "California", "Huston"]
```

And this above array I am trying to display in `UILabel`.

```
 cell.dynamicLbl.text = array.joined(separator: "\n")
```

even tried with following

```
 cell.dynamicLbl.text = array.joined(separator: ",")
```

but, its showing only first index of an array.
Even, I added label properties to show multiple lines.

```
    cell.dynamicLbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell.dynamicLbl.numberOfLines = 0
```

My total array is if I print in console

```
▿ 4 elements
  - 0 : "New York"
  - 1 : "Los Angeles"
  - 2 : "California"
  - 3 : "Huston"
```

And I already set my label with constraints.
PFA.

And took height constant for constraint and calculating the height of the text and assigning that float value to constraint constant.

```
@IBOutlet weak var optionsLblHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Still showing first data of array in label.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Out put

[image]

Comment: its shows only `only first index of an array.` or first line only

Comment: Did you check if your array actually contains all the cities? Also, that seems to be dictionary whose value is an array of cities.

Comment: Have you set your autolayout properly?

Comment: _"its showing only first index of an array."_ by this do you mean it shows only "NewYork"?

Comment: Yes, It is showing first city name in label. @Anbu.karthik

Comment: Then you'll probably have to check your constraints to make sure the label is big enough.

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri

Comment: what are the constraints ?. seems to be issue

Comment: can you add some additional code

Comment: Please show your storyboard or xib where you have designed your cell.

Comment: @iPeter added, please check

Comment: I am not able to understand, Why this question got down voted and what is the wrong with this query?

Comment: check my answer, you should not set the height manually.

Comment: I am not setting label height manually, I am doing it by dynamically calculating the height, That is why I took contraint outlet for height.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `cell.label.numberOfLines` is set to `0` and `lineBreakimgMode` to `.wordWrap`.

And cell constraints for top and bottom are set to contentView and heightForRow tableview func returns `tableview.automaticDimension`

Comment: I already set those properties, Please check my updated query. Thanks

Comment: Storyboard constraints can be one issue and also check what does your array.joined returns if you get one string then we can just say constraints are not given correctly that is why tableview is not able to calculate the height also try setting estimatedHeightForRow also to some value of 50.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `Height` for your label in the cell, try to set top, bottom, leading, trailing anchors.

You need to make sure that the label has auto layout set and it is anchored with `topAnchor` and `bottomAnchor` inside the cell. Afterwards set the following code inside `ViewDidLoad`

```
//this is to automatically manage the height of the label.
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
//give a approximate height for cell below
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the height constraint of your `UILabel`. Just add `trailing`, `leading`, `top` and `bottom` constraints.

No need to calculate height. Set `lineNumber` of your `UILabel` as **0**.

Inside `viewDidLoad` set the below properties of your `UITableView`.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Please check there should not be any height calculations anywhere and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` should not be written for this auto-resizing cells.

Comment: I have other labels after that, Thats the reason I took constant contraint for height of that label.

Comment: Show the whole cell. Will help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer, Its the issue with contraint relation.
Earlier it was like "Equal" relation.
After changing to "Grater Than or Equal" fixed the issue.

Hope this will help someone in future.

[image]